# Making a histogram that selects specific individuals

Tags: r, histogram

Sorry, but I am very new using R and have come up with a bit of an issue. I'm trying to make a histogram for all that have gender as male, and their answer to column s22 is either 2 or 4. The column s22 can be any number between 1 and 5.

my code is currently `hist(firstdata$second)[(firstdata$gender == "male")&(firstdata$s22 == 2)|(firstdata$s22 == 4)]`

The issue with this is that the histogram shows a frequency of individuals higher than the total amount of males (there are 40 males total, 92 individuals, and the histogram appears to show all individuals)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You may want to filter for males before giving the data to the histogram. Like this? : hist(yourdata[which(yourdata$gender=='M' & (...))])

Comment: To elaborate on @FlorianFasmeyer's suggestion: `firstdata[which(yourdata$gender == "male" & firstdata$s22 %in% c(2, 4))]` should select the subset you desire. Alternatively (and more elegantly) with the `dplyr` package: `firstdata %>% filter(gender == "male", s22 %in% c(2, 4))`

Comment: You should provid a sample of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I would comment instead but I don't have the reputation yet!)

I would approach this by first creating an object of that subset of data and *then* plotting it.

E.g. using the `which()` function

```
male_2_4 <- firstdata[which(firstdata$gender == "male" & (firstdata$s22 == 2 | firstdata$s22 == 4),]
hist(male_2_4$second)
```

Remember to specify if you want the or (`|`) to be just between either s22 = 2 or s22 = 4, then there needs to be brackets around those two arguments, otherwise it will not be separate from the `firstdata$gender == "male"` argument.

If you're new to using `which()` make sure you remember to add the last comma inside the square bracket, as you're subsetting by row rather than column.